# ngProgress plugin is making http calls in Jasmine unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a situation in my unit test where the ngProgress plugin is making http calls, which is messing up my unit tests as I am getting unexpected get errors:

> `Uncaught Error: Unexpected request: GET http://upda...`

here is the stack grace

```
> request(), app.js:35 deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback(),
> angular.js:10597 deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback(),
> angular.js:10597 anonymous(), angular.js:10683 $get.Scope.$eval(),
> angular.js:11576 $get.Scope.$digest(), angular.js:11421
> $get.Scope.$apply(), angular.js:11682 updateCount(),
> ngProgress.min.js:8 anonymous(), ngProgress.min.js:8
```

Comment: Try here https://github.com/victorbjelkholm/ngprogress/issues

Answer (score 1):

You can mock it out in your unit tests by redefining it as an empty module

```
angular.module('ngProgress', function() {});
```

Make sure your testing code that mocks the lib out is loaded by the browser after the file that defines the module, or excluded ngProgress file from loading altogether.